# How to open two different power point files one per each monitor?

Tags: microsoft-excel, multiple-monitors, microsoft-powerpoint

I have to work on power point file and I have to consult a similar one but I am not able to open those file on the two screen I have "installed" on my workstation.

It happened also with excel files, but not with word files.

I need it on office 2007 working on windows 7

Comment: Which version of Office are you using?

Comment: some programs you can get a second instance opened if you rename one of the executables, or to use an editor and a viewer only. dont know if that would work here.

Comment: If you want to open several presentations at once so you can copy and paste from one to the other. The usual way to do this with other programs is just to start two copies of the program.

PowerPoint won't allow this. It normally only permits one copy of itself to be open at a time. To sort off check this below link  ; http://smallbusiness.chron.com/open-two-powerpoint-presentations-separate-windows-56717.html

Answer (score 1):

Basically, though, open one of your presentations, then open the other.
Then choose Window, Arrange All (if in PPT 2003 or earlier) or View tab | Window group | Arrange all if in PPT 2007 or later.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-powerpoint/how-to-view-two-powerpoints-side-by-side/fd59395a-4a84-45c7-88e1-67166e145986

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I've had problems with that too. The easiest workaround is to open one file in Excel, then run Excel from the start menu and open the file through the file > open dialog.

Comment: The problem is with power point file not (this time) excel ones. I have modify the question just after your reply

Answer (score 0):

I usually open one Excel document and then "middle-mouse-click" the Excel icon in the taskbar. This opens up a new, empty Excel window and I open the second (or third, or fourth) document.

Office 2010 btw.

**EDIT:** OK, this never happens in PowerPoint on my machine...sorry